# Equation for the tangent plane and the normal line of $f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 + z$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have question: Find the equation for the tangent plane and the normal line of the surface

$f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z$

at point $(1,1,1)$

For the tangent plane I got, 
$z=2x+2y+z-2$

is this correct, if so from here how do I find the normal line?

Comment: Are you missing something? In the title you say $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2 +z$ and in the question $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+7$. Which one is right?

Comment: its $z$ not $7$, thanx for that observation, twas typing error

Answer (score 0):

The normal vector can be found using the gradient of the function computed at the point. Therefore $$\nabla f (1,1,1) = (2x,2y,1) \bigg\vert_{(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)} = (2,2,1)$$ is the normal vector of the tangent plane at $(1,1,1)$. Writing it as $2x+2y+z=d$ we substitute $(1,1,1)$ into the equation to find $d$, obtaining $$2x+2y+z=5.$$ As for the normal line, write it as every line: $$r: P_0 + t D,$$ where $P_0$ is the starting point and $D$ is the directing vector, the first vector we found..

Comment: is it $2x+2y+z=d$ or $2x+2y+1=d$, i didn't get that part